# Youtube Login with OpenID

Tags: php, openid, youtube-api

I want to create an web app which can get info about favourist, or another list were created. So, the first thing I think about is `How to login youtube with Google OpenID?`, and then I search but I don't get any useful information about this. Maybe, I have some wrong about my keyword, because I think Google must support it, but I'm not sure . So, I want to ask about `Can I login to youtube account with Google OpenID in another site to fect user data if they login successful?`

Comment: I answered this question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12662127

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use google Identity Toolkit.

It walks you though step by step on how to set it up, it gives you all of the code you need.

https://developers.google.com/identity-toolkit/

Answer (score 0):

Youtube uses the Google OpenID interface.

This post has some great references on OpenID Authentication with an example of PHP OpenID Authentication: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76184/php-tutorial-for-openid-and-oauth

Here is the Google Specific page on OpenID Authentication for their accounts: https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OpenID