# How to get user id after login with google oauth

Tags: google-api, youtube-api

I use Google oAuth to get user info via YoutubeAPI, but I don't know what I need to do after get `access_token` to retrieve userID, anybody please help me.

Comment: Please try printing the response from oauth once the authorization is done.. this will give you an idea of where to get user id from. It should be either inside "user_id" tag in response or inside "raw" tag.

Comment: This is redirect link after login with oauth
`http://localhost:8888/mbproject/user/oauth2callback?code=4/NWpMSgUcu9rXTlmWzZc0Zwj_BWYu.kotuJPCNkBYQgrKXntQAax186_w0dAI` , It's not includes user_id in GET parameter, just contain `code`

Comment: I actually use rails.. and i can see the result dump in `request.env["omniauth.auth"]` try this in your server code.. actually what's your backend server script?

Comment: Thanks balanv, it gives in user email in auth para result

Answer (score 6):

See Google's [OAuth2 documentation](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2Login#userinfocall) for how to get information about the logged in user.

It's basically just a GET call to `https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo` with a correct access token. In the response the user id is included.

Note that you also need to include the correct scope in your very first redirect to Google:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do one of the following:

1. perform a GET on `www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo`
2. decode the `id_token` that you get in the initial request, using a JWT library

I'd recommend the latter as it is more robust and doesn't require an extra call.

See this thread for more info: [How to identify a Google OAuth2 user?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8311836/how-to-identify-a-google-oauth2-user)

Comment: Decode the JWT https://developers.google.com/identity/openid-connect/openid-connect#obtainuserinfo

Answer (score 2):

If you're asking about how to get either the YouTube username or the YouTube user ID for the currently authenticated user, it can be found in the response to a [properly authenticated](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_authentication) request to

http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/default?v=2

Comment: Is it possible to list all YouTube channels per specific YouTube user if you are not that user?