# How can i get the userID of the youtube account?

Tags: ios, objective-c, youtube-api

I want to get the users youtube usedID. After successfully login with youTubeService. On the `viewController:finishedWithAuth:error:` userID returns nil.

```
Code

- (void)viewController:(GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch *)viewController
          finishedWithAuth:(GTMOAuth2Authentication *)auth
                     error:(NSError *)error
    {
        [viewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
        if(error != nil){
            NSLog(@"Authentication error: %@", error);
        }
        else {
            // Authentication succeeded...
            NSLog(@"%@",auth.accessToken);
            NSLog(@"%@",auth.userID); //returns nil
        }
    }
```

**Please note that I am not asking Google email ID I want to get youtube user id.**

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get user id after login with google oauth](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12662127/how-to-get-user-id-after-login-with-google-oauth)

Comment: i have seen this answer and i have also tried the userinfo URL to get the userid but actually it returns the google user id that i dont want. {
 "email": "XXX@gmail.com",
 "verified_email": true
}

Comment: Did you look at this answer in the suggested duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/a/12696891/449161

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are asking about "legacy" usernames. You can't get it from channel.

But if you know a username, you can find the channel with `channels.list(part="id", forUsername="username")`

On other hand, usernames are not unique, and not useful on the API. What you need instead is the channel ID.

[This guide describes it.](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/working_with_channel_ids#v3)

If you are looking a title to show, then you can use [channel's title](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels#snippet.title).

Comment: please open this link https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/3250431?hl=en in this youtube user ID that i want

Comment: If you only realize they are the same. Channel id has "UC" prefix that means it's a "U"ser "C"hannel.