# YouTube oauth how to request account details

Tags: php, oauth, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, google-oauth

So by using the youtube oauth documentation I came up with this way of getting the access token:

```
      /**
         * Get api authorization
         *
         * @return string
         */
        public function getAuthorizationUrl()
        {
            // Make redirect
            $this->params = [
                'client_id'    => '######',
                'redirect_uri' => '######',
                'scope'        => 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube',
                'response_type'=> 'code',
                'access_type'  => 'offline'
            ];
            $redirect_url = 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?' . http_build_query($this->params);
            return $redirect_url;
        }

        /**
         * Get API token and save account list to db
         *
         * @param $code
         *
         * @return \App\Models\DynamicDashboard\ThirdPartyAccounts
         */
        public function getCallbackUrl($code)
        {

            // Grab the returned code and extract the access token.
            $this->params = [
                'code'          => $code,
                'client_id'     => '#####',
                'client_secret' => '######',
                'redirect_uri'  => '######',
                'grant_type'    => 'authorization_code'
            ];

        // Get access token
        $command = 'curl --data "' . http_build_query($this->params) . '" https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token';
        exec($command, $token);
        $output = implode('', $token);
        $token = json_decode($output);

        // Do a request using the access token to get the list of accounts.
        $command = 'curl -H "Authorization: Bearer ' . $token->access_token . '" https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo';
        $result = $this->getRequest($command);

        //Do a request using the access token to get youtube account id.
        $command = 'curl -H "Authorization: Bearer ' . $token->access_token  . '"http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/default?v=2';
        exec($command, $youtube);
        var_dump($youtube); exit;

        //Do a request using the access token to get channel id.
        $command = 'curl -H "Authorization: Bearer ' . $token->access_token  . '"https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=id&mine=true';
        exec($command, $channel);
        $outputChannel = implode('', $channel);
        $channelId = json_decode($outputChannel);
    }
```

`var_dump` of `$youtube` return an empty array:

```
array {  
       }
```

So right now I have succeded in saving the google account but how can I get from that account the youtube account id or channel id? I tried to do that like this:

```
            //Do a request using the access token to get youtube account id.
            $command = 'curl -H "Authorization: Bearer ' . $token->access_token  . '"http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/default?v=2';
            exec($command, $youtube);
            var_dump($youtube); exit;

            //Do a request using the access token to get channel id.
            $command = 'curl -H "Authorization: Bearer ' . $token->access_token  . '"https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=id&mine=true';
            exec($command, $channel);
            $outputChannel = implode('', $channel);
            $channelId = json_decode($outputChannel);
```

But both variables: `$youtube` and `$channelId` return an empty array. Can anyone tell me why, please? Thank you for your help!

Comment: You mean google plus id

Comment: yes, sorry my bad, and account info like profile name

Comment: means you have got access token, and from using access token you want to get profile id and name, right?

Comment: indeed this is what I mean

Answer (score 0):

I have found this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12662127/how-to-get-user-id-after-login-with-google-oauth) which might help in getting user id after login via google oauth. You need a GET call to https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo with a correct access token. In the response, the user id is included. Here is the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OpenIDConnect#userinfocall).

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12696891/5832311) might also help.

> If you're asking about how to get either the YouTube username or the YouTube user ID for the currently authenticated user, it can be found in the response to a [properly authenticated](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_authentication) request to http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/default?v=2.

Comment: I have saved the google plus account but I don't know how to get details like youtube channel id. When I try the request it returns an empty array. I have edited my question.